# Does puppet check attributes sequentially?

Tags: puppet, selinux

I've noticed something in my puppet environment.  Note that I'm new, and it's very possible that I did something wrong.

I have a class that says, in part, this:

```
  File 
  {
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0700',
    seluser  => 'system_u',
    selrole  => 'object_r',
    seltype  => 'bin_t',
    selrange => 's0',
  }
  file { "/root/SEPreset.sh" :
    ensure => file,
    source => $filesource,
  }
```

I'm going to draw to your attention that the SELinux context for this file is not the standard SELinux context for `/root` .

So I updated the source file.  On the next run, Puppet applied the new file.  On the next run after that, Puppet changed the SELinux context.

This says to me that, during the first run, Puppet

- checked the SELinux context and saw that it matched
- checked the file content and saw that it was wrong
- created a new file that inadvertently had the wrong context

It seems to me that Puppet **should** have double-checked, after applying the new file, that **all** of the attributes were correct.  I would be very disappointed if, for example, it created a file but left the ownership or permissions set to whatever the default happened to be.

Is this a Puppet bug, or a mistake in my class definition, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: I call bug, could you open a [ticket](http://tickets.puppetlabs.com/)?

Comment: Yes, Puppet should not require two runs to achieve the target state for any individual resource.